# How to set the default value to the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to set the default value to dropdown menu?

```
<div class="row form-group">
<label class="col-md-3"><b>NAME<span style="color: #b94a48">*</span></b></label> 
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-7" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="dropdown multiple" style="width: 100%;">
        <select name="i" class="dropdown multiple" ng-model="i" ng-options="obj.name as obj.name for obj in uniqueMultiSlectStrataList" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="Retail" selected>Retail</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

assign a value `ng-model="i"` in controller

```
$scope.i = 'Retail';
```

it will make it selected